# QR matrices column space different

Tags: linear-algebra

Do the $Q$ and $R$ matrices in QR-decomposition necessarily have different column spaces? Why or why not? This appears in a lecture note but given without further explanation, but I really want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not necessarily different. For example, take $A = QR$ with $A = Q = R = I$.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I wonder if there is another example that is not $I$.

Comment: @apen If $A$ is invertible $n \times n$, then $Q$ and $R$ are invertible, so they have the same column space, namely $\mathbb{R}^n$.